# how to do case switch statement in csh

Tags: csh

In sh, I know I can do something like the following...

```
#!/sbin/sh

case "$1" in
'foo')
/path/to/foo.sh
;;
'bar')
/path/to/bar.sh
;;
*)
echo $"Usage: $0 {foo|bar}"
exit 1
;;
esac
```

I've searched the entirety of the internets and can't seem to find a corresponding switch statement that matches what I'm trying to do above.

Before we get too much further; I know, I know, I shouldn't be using csh, but I have a legacy app that only runs in csh.  I'm trying to build a Solaris SMF service for it and I've already tried setting the shell but whatever shell is used in the method file overwrites the actual SMF shell.  So it has to be in csh.

Thanks in advance for any help provided.

> **tl;dr** (How do you convert the above to csh?)

Comment: `man csh` gives some reference material regarding `case` and `switch`.

Comment: So would that be something like:
switch $1
case foo:
/path/to/foo.sh
breaksw
case bar:
/path/to/bar.sh
breaksw
default:
breaksw
endsw

...sorry I can't seem to format stuff in a comment.

Comment: Ya gotta love Solaris and their never-ending backwards compatibility layers that let old legacy apps that should have died in the last millenium keep running.

Answer (score 3):

I'm glad to see you're aware of the downfalls of C-Shell.

Here is the same script, converted to C-shell (**Edit**: updated to output `$usage` in cases of no args, or more than 1 arg):

```
#!/usr/bin/env csh

set usage="Usage: $0 {foo|bar}"

if ( $#argv != 1 ) then
  echo $usage
else
  switch ($argv[1])
  case 'foo':
    /path/to/foo.sh
    breaksw
  case 'bar':
    /path/to/bar.sh
    breaksw
  default:
    echo $usage
    breaksw
  endsw
endif
```

Comment: thanks.  there was an extraneous dollar sign after the echo.

Comment: `argv: Subscript out of range.` when called without arguments. Why not use `"$1"`? And `exit 1` is missing.

Comment: there was no test for the existence of arguments in the original, so I didn't add it here, but yes.  With no arguments, it does error out.